# Playwright waitFor changed innerText to be exact value

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I have an innerText that changed after 2-3 sec from `Loading` to `Play` . I would like to wait for the innerText to change to `Play`. I'm using the following code :

```
let attempt = 0;
let maxRetries = 4;

let payerButtonStatus = await this.player_page.innerText('#playingStatus');
while (attempt < maxRetries) {
    if (payerButtonStatus !== 'Loading') {
        console.log(`payerButtonStatus = ${payerButtonStatus}`);
        return true;
    }
    console.log(`Playback button status is - ${payerButtonStatus}, wait for 1sec and continue... ${attempt}/${maxRetries}`);
    await this.player_page.waitForTimeout(1000);
    payerButtonStatus = await this.player_page.innerText('#playingStatus');
    console.log(`payerButtonStatus= ${payerButtonStatus}`);
    attempt++;
}
return false;
```

Is there a better code to write this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [text selector](https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#text-selector) on a [waitForSelector](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector). It will wait for 30 seconds by default:

```
await this.player_page.waitForSelector('text=Play');
```

Comment: await this.player_page.waitForSelector('#playingStatus:has-text("Playing")'); also works

Answer (score 0):

Since the use of both [text selector](https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#legacy-text-locator) and [waitForSelector](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector) is discouraged according to the docs, here the recommended way:

```js
const myLocator = this.player_page.getByText('Play')
await myLocator.waitFor()
```