# How do I properly wait for the result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, playwright

In an integration test, I have code similar to this:
(combined here into one function for easy reading)

```
    [Test]
    public async Task DeleteTagTest(IPage page)
    {
        // get the context
        TagsContext? tagsContext;
        using var scope = Fixture.Services.CreateScope();
        tagsContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TagsContext>();

        if(tagsContext == null) {
            throw new Exception("Tags context is null");
        }

        // Arrange
        // create the tag
        int tagID = tagsContext.CreateTag("tagNumber1", 1, "c40rj8f");

        // Act
        // go to the scan page
        await page.GotoAsync(Fixture.ServerAddress + "Scan");
        await page.WaitForLoadStateAsync(LoadState.DOMContentLoaded);

        // find the delete button
        var deletebutton = await page.QuerySelectorAsync("#delete");
        // invoke delete
        await deletebutton.ClickAsync();
        await page.WaitForLoadStateAsync(LoadState.Load);

        // Assert            
        // check that it got deleted
        Assert.AreEqual(0, tagsContext.Tags.Where(x => x.ID == tagID).ToList().Count);
        // This assert fails if run normally, but succeeds if debug and step through
    }
```

If I step through the code, it completes correctly, otherwise fails with
Actual - 1
Expected - 0
So I think it is a timing issue and the backend delete hasn't actually finished yet when the assert runs.

Adding ".GetAwaiter().GetResult()" to the async method doesn't help.

The ajax on the delete button looks like this:

```
deleteTagBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    console.log(qrKey + ': ' + tagNumber);
    $.ajax({
        url: `/api/Scans/Delete?QRKey=${qrKey}&tagNumber=${tagNumber}`,
        method: 'DELETE',
        
        success: function (response) {
            $('#output').html('Tag Deleted Successfully.');
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            $('#output').html('Tag Deletion Failed.');
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Playwright suggests waiting for a visible change on the page.
Perhaps wait for the output tag to be visible, like:

```
var output = page.Locator("#output");
await output.WaitForAsync();
```

But that causes the test to crash. ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Comment: You may be doing fine your `output.WairForAsync()` but you `(event)` is not waiting to the ajax call completion. Have you tried adding `async : false,` to the `$.ajax()` parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your JavaScript's call to `ajax` is basically a fire-and-forget call you have to wait for the side effects to be observable - in your case the value of `#output` element to be updated with either success or failure message.

How to  [Playwright waitFor changed innerText to be exact value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70833894/playwright-waitfor-changed-innertext-to-be-exact-value):

```
await this.player_page.waitForSelector('#output:has-text("Successfully")');
```

Comment: That makes sense. I haven't gotten it to work yet, but this is clearly the direction forward, so I'm marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var locator = Page.Locator("locatorForRecordCount");
await Expect(locator).ToHaveCountAsync(0);
```

[ToHaveCountAsync](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-count) will wait and retry for the count to reach at expected value.